# HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 415, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: json, angular, typescript, csv, angular11

Hi I tried to upload a csv file and convert it to json array and pass to the web api. But when I click the submit button I am getting this error. Anyone who can help to fix this?
Thank you :)

**This is my .ts file in angular** Here I tried to upload a csv file and convert it to json array.

```
    changeListener(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
      const file = event.target.files[0];
      this.myForm.patchValue({
        fileSource: file
      });

      //File reader method
      let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        let csv: any = reader.result;
        let allTextLines = [];
        allTextLines = csv.split(/\r|\n|\r/);
        console.log('CSV: ', csv?.toString());
      }

      //JSON.stringify(file);
    }
  }

  submit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.myForm.get('fileSource')?.value);

    this.http.post('http://localhost:64233/api/employee', formData)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        alert('Upload Sussessful');
      })
  }
```

**This is my .html file in angular**

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">

    <h1 style="text-align: center">File Upload</h1>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file">File</label>
        <input class="form-control" formControlName="file" id="file" type="file" class="upload"
            (change)="changeListener($event)" />
    </div>

    <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**This is the error I get when I click on submit button**

[image]

I checked my web api in postman and it is working fine for json array. Really appreciate if you can help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I am talking to myself. But this is to help others.

Here in my .ts file, I have uploaded the file and read the data in the csv file as a string. But I have not converted it to json array correctly and push it to go to the web api.

So below is the working code. This may not be the perfect one but it works fine for me.

**This is my .ts file in angular**

```
  export class FileUploadComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm = new FormGroup({
    file: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public fileUploadService: FileUploadService,
    private toastr: ToastrService, private router: Router) { }

  obj: any;
  unique: any;
  removeHeader: any;
  // Maximum file size allowed to be uploaded = 1MB
  maxSize: number = 1048576;

  //upload file
  fileUpload(event: any) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      // Don't allow file sizes over 1MB
      if (event.target.files[0].size < this.maxSize) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        console.log(file);

        //File reader method
        let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(file);
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          let csv: any = reader.result;
          let res: any[] = csv.split("\n");

          //remove first element of the array
          res.shift();

          let jsonArray: any = [];

          res.forEach(item => {
            let singlePerson = item.split(",");
            let singleObject = { employeeid: singlePerson[0], firstname: singlePerson[1], lastname: singlePerson[2], address: singlePerson[3] }
            jsonArray.push(singleObject);
          })
          this.obj = jsonArray;

          //check duplicates in csv file, remove, and return unique records
          let unique = this.obj
            .map((e: { [x: string]: any; }) => e['employeeid'])
            .map((e: any, i: any, final: string | any[]) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
            .filter((obje: string | number) => this.obj[obje])
            .map((e: string | number) => this.obj[e]);

          this.obj = unique;
        }
      }
      else {
        // Display error message
        this.toastr.error("File is too large to upload");
      }
    }
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.myForm.reset();
  }

  submit() {
    this.fileUploadService.postFileUpload(this.obj);
    this.resetForm();
  }
}
```

**This is my html file**

```
<br /><br />

<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <h1 style="text-align: center">File Upload</h1>
  <br /><br />

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="file" style="font-size: 25px">File</label>
    <input
      class="form-control"
      formControlName="file"
      type="file"
      accept=".csv"
      class="upload"
      (change)="fileUpload($event)"
    />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label> Please Upload a CSV or Text file of size less than 1MB </label>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="submit()">
    Submit
  </button>
</form>
```

**This is my service class**

```
export class FileUploadService {

  messages: string[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private toastr: ToastrService) { }

  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:64233/api/employee';

  myForm = new FormGroup({
    file: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  });

  formData: FileUpload = new FileUpload();

  //method for post request
  postFileUpload(body: any) {
    const requestOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'content-type': "application/json" }) };
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, body, requestOptions)
      .subscribe(
        observer => {
          this.toastr.success("File Uploaded Succesfully");
          this.resetForm();
        },
        err => {
          if (err.status == 500)
            this.toastr.error("Empty File");

          else
          this.toastr.error("Please upload a file");
            //console.log(err);
          /* (error) => {
            console.log(error); */
          //throw new Error(error);
        });
  }

  resetForm() {
    this.myForm.reset();
    this.formData = new FileUpload();
  }
}
```

Here to display alerts I have used a toaster